# Javascript Uncaught ReferenceError: parameter is not defined

Tags: javascript

I have some Javascript code:

```
function addRow(tableID, rowId) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowPosition = document.getElementById(rowID).rowIndex;
//etc.
}
```

But this throws a Javascript error

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: rowID is not
>   defined"

Though looking on Firebug, I can see that the functions receives a correct row identifier, but once the code reaches the second line inside the function the parameter `rowID` seems unknown.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. You've used `rowId` as the argument name (small "d") while inside the function you have `rowID` (capital "D"). Change the argument to `rowID` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You're passing the parameter `rowId`, but referencing it `rowID`. Variable names are case sensitive, they both need to be the same.